# Limit checkbox based on value JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to create a checkbox limit based on a value change example:
I have the following checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2[]" onClick="setChecks(this)" value="`key`=<?php 
echo $rspatient['key']?>" class="chk" id="chk<?php echo $a++?>" />
```

I have a lot of check box as this is in a loop. Some have the same value others do not. Anyways wanting to create code that prevents checking boxes with different values!

Current code for limiting checkbox number:

```
<script>
 <!--
 //initial checkCount of zero 
 var checkCount = 0
 //maximum number of allowed checked boxes 
 var maxChecks = 3
 var d = document.getElementById('chk' + (j++));

 function setChecks(obj) {
     //increment/decrement checkCount 
     if (obj.checked) {
         checkCount = checkCount + 1
     } else {
         checkCount = checkCount - 1
     }
     //if they checked a 4th box, uncheck the box, then decrement checkcount and pop alert 
     if (checkCount > maxChecks) {
         obj.checked = false
         checkCount = checkCount - 1
         alert('you may only choose up to ' + maxChecks + ' options')
     }
 }
 // -->
</script>
```

I tried to edit the final if statement with no luck!

Comment: Where are you initializing "checkCount"?

Comment: one line above lol '<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!-- 
//initial checkCount of zero 
var checkCount=0  @Diodeus

//maximum number of allowed checked boxes 
var maxChecks=3
var d=document.getElementById('chk'+(j++));

function setChecks(obj){ '

Comment: I suggest to remove the `<!--`, `-->` lines from your code. They serve no purpose.

Comment: your correct im trying to limit based on value this limits based on number of checked boxes!@FelixKling

Comment: the checkbox value value="`key`=<?php 
echo $rspatient['key']?>"@FelixKling  @Diodeus

Comment: I think you need to re-phrase your question. This is vague and confusing.

Comment: Im trying to create a checkbox limit based on a value change example: I have the following checkbox

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2[]" onClick="setChecks(this)" value="`key`=<?php 
echo $rspatient['key']?>" class="chk" id="chk<?php echo $a++?>" /> @Diodeus

Comment: I said "re-phrase" not "repeat".

Comment: am trying to create a checkbox limit based on a value change example:If the value of a checked checked box is different then the previous prompt an alert! Some of the check boxes do have the same value. Not all of them!@Diodeus 

Example:

<input name="" type="checkbox" value="here">(if this was checked)
<input name="" type="checkbox" value="here">(then this)
<input name="" type="checkbox" value="there">(would not allow prompt alert) 
<input name="" type="checkbox" value="here">(would allow)
key=" class="chk" id="chk" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some messing around i managed to end up with this a working solution!

```
1 <input type="checkbox" value="1" /><br/>
2 <input type="checkbox" value="2" /><br/>
3 <input type="checkbox" value="3" /><br/>
1 <input type="checkbox" value="1" /><br/>
2 <input type="checkbox" value="2" /><br/>
3 <input type="checkbox" value="3" /><br/>
1 <input type="checkbox" value="1" /><br/>
2 <input type="checkbox" value="2" /><br/>
3 <input type="checkbox" value="3" /><br/>

$(function() {
var lastChecked = [];
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        if (lastChecked.length && this.value != lastChecked[0].value) {
            this.checked = false;
            alert("the last box you checked has a different value");
        }
        else
        {
            lastChecked.unshift(this);
        }
    }
    else {
        lastChecked.splice(lastChecked.indexOf(this), 1);
    }
});
});​
```

​

Answer (score 0):

```
 lastChecked.splice(lastChecked.indexOf(this), 1);
}
```

});
});​